# REST Routes and overriding :id with to_param

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, parameters

My controller is using the default RESTful routes for creating, adding, editing etc

I want to change the default `:id` to use `:guuid`. So what I did was:

```
# routes.rb
resources :posts

# Post Model
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    def to_param  # overridden
        guuid
    end
end
```

This works but my modifed REST controller code has something like this

```
def show
  @post = Post.find_by_guuid(params[:id])
  @title = "Review"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
  end
end
```

When I see this this code ..

```
Post.find_by_guuid(params[:id])
```

it would seem wrong but it works.
I don't understand why I can't write it out like this:

```
Post.find_by_guuid(params[:guuid])
```

Why do I still have to pass in the `params[:id]` when I'm not using it?
Looking for feedback on whether my approach is correct or anything else to consider.
Even though it works it doesn't always mean it's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `rake routes` in your console, and check the output of the routes. You'll see the fragment ':id' in some of them, that's where the `params[:id]` comes from. It's a rails convention : when you use `resources` in your routes, the parameter is named `id`. I don't know if you can change it (while keeping `resources`; otherwise you could just go with matching rules), but you shouldn't anyway : even if it seems not very logic, it actually has sense, once your understand how rails routing works.

Comment: OK, if it's a rails convention then I'll stick with it. I just thought their could be another way of overriding it in the routes. Thanks for the feedback.